# How to implement transaction support for LevelDB in Java?

Tags: java, database, transactions, key-value-store, leveldb

I am currently using [leveldbjni-1.8](https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni) to implement a LevelDB based database. But it only supports basic operations like put(),get(),delete() and iterate() and there is no any transaction support to the database. When I searched for libraries for providing transaction support for LevelDB, most of them were JavaScript libraries like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/level-transactions). But I require either a Java library which supports LevelDB transactions or any other separate transaction layer to implement in the application. So, is there any suggestions to implement transaction support for LevelDB in Java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: leveldb's writebatch might be what you need

Comment: @ren WirteBatch can only provide atomicity for the operations. I require a better transaction support which covers all ACID properties. I am actually looking for a library like  https://www.npmjs.com/package/level-transactions for Java.

Comment: together with snapshots writebatch can provide atomicity, consistency and isolation as far as I see it. Durability is questionable in case of a power loss since in this case leveldb might get corrupted. More about it https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/leveldb/qp67jTW5Yb8